# how to execute the linux terminal custom command using java

Tags: java, linux, shell, hadoop

I have  binary of engine already developed with `Hadoop(HDFS,HBASE,MAPREDUCE)` and java which is  use to generate CSV file. There are some operation performed by this engine like table creation in HBASE and generating the CSV File from this HBASE. But this engine is performed all operation through  only  command line , as input  is given from Linux terminal in form of command. Now my requirement is to connect this Linux terminal Through java program and run the commands But I am not able to successfully run any of the command

There are two option I tried but none of them successfully worked. Please provide any suggestion or solution to solve this problem as  I am just beginner of Linux and hadoop to figure out the problem

1st-way

```
public class EngineTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
Process process = Runtime
                .getRuntime()
            .exec("/home/cloudera/PVGproto/Base/ anloss -i ${TOOL_INPUT}/census_10000_col5.csv  -d ${TOOL_DEF}/attr_all_def.txt -q k=14,dage=2 -g ${TOOL_RES}/census_100_col8_gen.csv");

            process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        String output = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            output += line + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

2nd-way

I made one `ex.sh` file, in this file I put the required command for execution and call this `. sh` file from the same java program but the same thing happened its not running the command through java program

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/cloudera/PVGproto/Base/ex.sh");
```

but if I run the same ex.sh from Linux terminal its running all the command successfully.

ex.sh

```
# !/bin/bash
 exec /home/cloudera/PVGproto/Base/ anloss -i ${TOOL_INPUT}/census_10000_col5.csv  -d ${TOOL_DEF}/attr_all_def.txt -q k=14,age=2 -g ${TOOL_RES}/census_100_col8_gen.csv
   echo command run successfully
```